# How to determine DOCX file and PPTX file?

Tags: winforms

I try to read the file header DOCX files and PPTX files to determine if two files, but the two files have the same header.
How can I distinguish PPTX and DOCX.

Comment: Check file extension.

Comment: if checking the file extension when changing the file extension will allow the application to upload files.

Comment: I'm not totally sure how to answer this question, but as a suggestion, you might consider adding some more tags, if you can think of some relevant ones that already exist. Also, some details from the files themselves? Have you tried anything already? :)

Comment: I still do not really understand the structure of the file format of MS * X because they all have the same header file and resembles the .zip file..
I'll try to find out what's the difference between these files.
Thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450947/find-out-the-real-file-type